# I am trying to turn on a led using a switch in Raspberry pi. Now when I am trying to run it in python command shell it says: command not found

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, led

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)

input = GPIO.input(17)

while True:

  if (GPIO.input(17)):

    print("Button Pressed")

    import time



prev_input = 0

while True:


  input = GPIO.input(17)

  if ((not prev_input) and input):

    print("Button pressed")

  prev_input = input

  #slight pause to debounce

  time.sleep(0.05)
```

this the code I am executing.

Comment: Could you edit your post and say what you type in to run the script?

Comment: i figured out my mistake. but encountered  a new issue.

Comment: If you have solved the problem could you edit your post to say how it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning to programp Raspberry PI in Python.

Take a look at this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/ for a general overview and for that specific case, look at:

Using buttons to get input

Now you're able to control an output component (an LED), let's connect and control an input component: a button.

```
Connect a button to another GND pin and GPIO pin 2, like this:

Create a new file by clicking File > New file.

Save the new file by clicking File > Save. Save the file as gpio_button.py.

This time you'll need the Button class, and to tell it that the button is on pin 2. Write the following code in your new file:

from gpiozero import Button
button = Button(2)

Now you can get your program to do something when the button is pushed. Add these lines:

button.wait_for_press()
print('You pushed me')

Save with Ctrl + S and run the code with F5.
Press the button and your text will appear.
```

source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/worksheet/

I Hope that info is useful.

Felipe